# Login Customer WooCommerce API

Tags: wordpress, api, vue.js, woocommerce

We are building an Easy Order form in VUE for our customers. The VUE app is connected to the WooCommerce API v3. Customers should login with their own credentials and be able to order products. We managed to let it work with an admin user, but it looks like customers don’t have the correct credentials.

Is there a way to fix this? Maybe with a plugin? Or code?

All the other related posts are pretty old. So I hope this is possible now.

Answer (score 1):

The login is managed by the [WordPress Rest API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/).

For more info I recommend reading the following:

1. [WC REST API Order Properties](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?php#order-properties)
2. [WP-API / Basic-Auth repo](https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth)
3. [WooCommerce / wc-api-php repo](https://github.com/woocommerce/wc-api-php)
4. [WP plugin Simple JWT Login](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-jwt-login/#description)